# SLURM: Is it normal for slurmd.service to fail when my internet connection is off? It really needs internet? why? using one computer only

Tags: server, slurm

I installed slurm in a single computer that serves as the management and compute node at the same time. when WiFi is off.. slurmd.service fail and show a get_address() error failure. When internet is on. it works fine..
Is it normal? and Why?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slurmd` daemon periodically talks with its siblings and the controller, and must therefore be able to translate their names into an IP address. Even if there is only one machine in the cluster. When you shut down the WiFi, it appears the DNS service is not able to resolve any name, include that of your machine.

Try adding your computer name in the `/etc/hosts` file of your computer. Make sure to use the same name as listed in the `slurm.conf` file.